# Slope and mosaics

Tags: raster, arcmap, mosaic, slope, mosaic-dataset

[image: The top shows the values I have been getting after the mosaic to new raster tool. below is the values I have been getting for each smaller slope chunk. The above is showing raster catalog to new raster which I also tried. both traster catalog to new raster and mosaic to new raster come out with these wrong figures][image][image]I have used a large number of Gtopo30 altitude tiles and used the mosaic tool to create a large DEM for my area of interest. I am trying to get a slope for said area but when running the slope (Spatial analyst) tool I have large gaps. I split the large DEM up into smaller chunks and successfully run the slope tool on each. I am now trying to mosaic them together into a single layer. I have tried mosaic to new raster but this is not showing the full area and also the values have changed. originally my slope would vary anywhere from 0 up to around 85 but after running the mosaic to new raster 7.xxx is the smallest value and it rises to over 2000. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong or another way of putting the multiple slopes together into one.

Comment: Could you prove a screenshot of the settings you chose in `Mosaic to New Raster`?

Comment: I mean provide, not prove, sorry.

Comment: @blabbath Ive added screen shots above. Im trying to add a picture to show the output I am currently getting but Im having trouble at the minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think your problem is in the chosen `Pixel type`.
Check the smallest and largest values in all your rasters - or just choose a `Pixel type`that surely fits your range. Click the drop down menu and in the right field you can read which one is right for you.
On a slope raster `16-bit signed` should be a wide enough range.

Comment: I have tried with the 16-bit signed pixel type and I am am still getting the incorrect values.